# Get result sorted by "@timestamp" in python using elasticsearch-dsl

Tags: python-2.7, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-dsl-py

I want get the data from my elasticsearch node for my code, i am using elasticsearch-dsl library to query the data from elasticsearch. Now i want the data to be sorted according to the "@timestamp" which can done using **sort api**. But the data that i am getting back has **more than 10000 documents**. I cannot use scan with sort to get large data as with **sort doesn't work with scan** in elasticsearch-dsl. Is there a way to use scroll api in elasticsearch-dsl or any other way to get more than **10000 document sorted with "@timestamp"**.

Answer (score 2):

`scroll` does work with `sort`, you just need to call it with `preserve_order`: `s.params(preserve_order=True).scan()`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Its showing this error :- "ScanError: Scroll request has failed on 30 shards out of 32" when i am using the above setting

Comment: What is the error that you are getting? Catch the exception and print its `.info` property

Comment: "error:Scroll request has failed on 38 shards out of 41"  this is error i am getting.

Comment: That's just the message, please catch the exception and print out its `.info` property. This is just telling you what went wrong, not why, it is of no help

Comment: this is the traceback:- Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "check_dsl.py", line 41, in run_query
    for hit in response:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch_dsl/search.py", line 701, in scan
    **self._params
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/helpers/__init__.py", line 316, in scan
    (resp['_shards']['failed'], resp['_shards']['total'])
ScanError: Scroll request has failed on 41 shards out of 44.

Comment: s = Search().query(q).sort("@timestamp")
    try:
        response = s.params(preserve_order=True).scan()

Comment: i am using the above code, now after this if i am doing:- "print response" o/p is coming:-  "<generator object scan at 0x7fcc175caaf0>" and if i am trying to iterate over the response i am getting the above error.

Comment: The traceback is not needed, just the `info` property: `try: scan(...) except Exception as e: print(e.info)`

Comment: i tried this, it says 'ScanError' object has no attribute 'info'

Comment: fwiw, I came across this because my results were not sorted when using `scan()`. Adding `.params(preserve_order=True)` to the query fixed it. So I assume that this answer can be accepted, and that the shard-failures mentioned in the comments are unrelated?